# Строка с header'ом на текущую страницу пораждает ошибку

Tags: php, sql, header

Имееться файл form.php следующего содержания:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<?php
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];

    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'mydb');
    mysqli_query($link, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");

    $query = "INSERT INTO users SET id='$id', name='$name'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or
        die(mysqli_error($link));

    unset($_POST);
    header('Location: form.php');
}
?>

<form method="POST">
    <input name="id">
    <input name="name">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

При нажатии кнопки отправки данные введеные в форму улетают в базу данных. Header призванный для исключения дубляжа, вместо возложенных на него обязанностей выводит ошибку следующего вида **Warning**: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\OpenServer\domains\newProject\form.php:1) in **C:\OpenServer\domains\newProject\form.php** on line **15** на страницу. По итогу имеем переполнение базы дубликатами и захламлённую страницу с формой. Каждое обновление страницы порождает запись той же информации, хотя поля формы пусты - это раз и удалён массив ПОСТ - это два. Это как так понимать? Откуда в таком разе беруться данные и как вообще выполняется запрос находящийся в if'е если после удаления массива способом `unset($_POST)` условие `!empty($_POST)` становиться ложным(во всяком случае должно становиться). Действительно ли описаное выше условие станет ложным если Header чудесным образом заработает, что для этого нужно? Что я только не пробовал за эти несколько дней: И записывал некую переменную логическую переменную в куки, a затем  до if'а пытался удалить пост. И менял empty() на isset(). И насильно менял значения POST[id] и POST[name] на пустату. И даже сделал отдельный файлик куда также, как в случае с куками, записывал логическое значение, после чего мне даже удалось победить злопоучное дублирование данных в базу без применения headera, но увы лишь частично. Перед тем как открыть шампанское, я повторно обновил страницу и данные которые минуту назад были удалены (как мне казалось) снова откуда невозьмись записались в базу. Данные попрежнему записывались в базу данных с тем лишь отличием от предыдущих способов, что делали это раз в 2 обновления. Вобщем я исчерпал все свои идеи и надеюсь на внятный ответ бывалых знатоков.

Comment: читайте как работает `header` (в документации например) и что до него не должно быть никакого вывода в output...... а у вас уже  `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Comment: Действительно, как же всё просто 5 сек. и всё заработало, а я несколько дней маялся не зная что делать. Благодарю тебя добрый человек, удачи и всех благ тебе!